# Stratus player no longer loads tracks from on page anchor tags

Tags: soundcloud

I know there's limited support for Stratus at this point in time, but for the record...

After the stratus.sc downtime on 2014-07-25, the Stratus player will no longer play from anchor tags with a .stratus class.

This seems to be a CORS issue.

The output from Chrome's dev console:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://stratus.sc') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://www.stratus.sc').

I use a locally hosted stratus.js file, because I've made some tweaks to allow for AJAX friendly link loading, but even the natively hosted stratus.js fails because it has a hard coded reference to stratus.sc.

However, that page is impossible to get to because stratus.sc  now force redirects to www.stratus.sc, which as the Chrome error message shows, is considered a different domain by the stratus.sc server.

The offending line in stratus.js seems to be:

```
$.postMessage($(this).attr('href'), src, $('#stratus iframe')[0].contentWindow);
```

The postMessage method itself is working, but the parent window can no longer pass the parameters to the stratus iframe due to a stricter cross domain policy on the stratus server.

Hopefully someone can look at the server configuration and restore the previous functionality.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I lost patience and solved the issue for me personally by registering my own Soundcloud API key, downloading the relevant Stratus files off stratus.sc, and reconfiguring everything to run locally.

Everything seems to be working at this point and on the bright side, I'll now be able to customize the behavior to better fit my site needs as well as for current jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also host the stratus.js file locally and make a small update to accommodate the redirect.

Change:

```
    ... 'http://example.com:3000' : 'http://stratus.sc';
```

To:

```
    ... 'http://example.com:3000' : 'http://www.stratus.sc';
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve any issues I'm aware of.

The hosted stratus player still 'works', even with the www redirect, it's just the ability to interact with the iframed player from the parent window that's broken.

My point in bringing up the www redirect was that the iframe interaction is broken even on the stratus demo page itself, because the CORS policy is now so strict, it views www.stratus.sc and stratus.sc as two completely unrelated domains.

Comment: I looked into it further, and restored my old set up to test this.

You're right, this solution now works, but it's because in the time since I made my post, the CORS policy on stratus.sc has been relaxed to treat www.stratus.sc and stratus.sc as the same domain.

Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Before, line 180 in http://www.stratus.sc/js/player.js would prevent this workaround from being effective.

Answer (score -1):

To make this feature work again:

1. Download the script from http://www.stratus.sc/stratus.js
2. Open the script in your text-editor & change in line 10: "stratus.sc' to "www.stratus.sc"
3. Upload the edited script to your server.
4. In the head tags of your webpage, locate the stratus library to the new location on your server.
   e.g. 
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stratus.sc/stratus.js"></script>`

becomes

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourdomain.com/scripts/stratus.js"></script>`

Now, links with 'stratus'-class should play again in the stratus-player

Comment: As mentioned in my original post: "that page is impossible to get to because stratus.sc now force redirects to www.stratus.sc" (from my original post)

In case it's not clear, the stratus.js file utilizes js scripts for the actual player hosted on stratus.sc. Even if you locally host the initial script, your page still won't be independent of javascript hosted by stratus.sc.

Comment: You have to download those additional files off stratus.sc, host them locally, and register your own api key to access the soundcloud api.

Comment: That's pretty odd as I had the same problem as you. I've solved the issue by doing the thing mentioned here-above.

Comment: I looked into it further, and restored my old set up to test this.

You're right, this solution now works, but it's because in the time since I made my post, the CORS policy on stratus.sc has been relaxed to treat www.stratus.sc and stratus.sc as the same domain.

Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Before, line 180 in http://www.stratus.sc/js/player.js would prevent this workaround from being effective.